# How can we find the coordinates or position of element using jquery mobile/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

The code i am using is this for  a mobile app. I want to find  out the position of the current selected object on our mobile screen>here I have two paragraph element id "#first" and "#second" whose position i am trying to find.But it always return me `HTML coords (0,0)`   in result. I guess this is becoz i am using jquery function .postion() instead of jquery mobile function. Please help

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $("*", document.body).click(function (e) {
     var offset = $(this).position();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $("#result").text(this.tagName + " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " +
                                  offset.top + " )");
     });

    </script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
     <div data-role="content" id="objects">
        <p id="first">1st object</p>
        <p id="second">2nd object</p>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>


</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#first,#second').click(function () {
       $("#result").text(this.tagName + " coords ( " + $(this).position().left + ", " + $(this).position().top + " )");
    });        
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CKG9U/

Comment: not working for me in mobile...... it's not able to find the coordinates and neither raising any exception.result container remains empty

Comment: The jsfiddle example runs fine on my Android HTC Evo in a PhoneGap wrapper